# Authentication via decorators in Flask

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, python-decorators

I have the following code which works. It authenticates admin users for the given url. If the users is not Admin then it returns a 401.

Snippet 1:

```
__author__ = 'xxxx'

from flask import render_template, url_for
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, request, session, abort
from google.appengine.api import users


admin_routes = Blueprint('admin_routes', __name__)


@admin_routes.route('/xxxx')
def basic():
    user = users.get_current_user()

    if user:
        if not users.is_current_user_admin():
            return abort(401)
        else:
            return render_template('xxx/xxxx.html', user=user, 
                                   logout=users.create_logout_url('/'))
    else:
        return redirect(users.create_login_url('/xxxx'))
```

The above code works and I wanted to make a decorator out of it. So I wrote the following. However it does not work, as the value of

> user = None

Snippet 2:

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from flask import abort, redirect


def authenticate_admin(func):
    def authenticate_and_call(*args, **kwargs):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user is None:
            print("Redirecting user to login page")
            return redirect(users.create_login_url('xxxxx/xxxx'), 401)
        else:
            if not users.is_current_user_admin():
                return abort, 401
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return authenticate_and_call()
```

How would I write the decorator so it does what the Snippet 1 does. End result should be something like so.

```
__author__ = 'xxxxxx'

from flask import render_template, url_for
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, request, session, abort
from google.appengine.api import users


admin_routes = Blueprint('admin_routes', __name__)

@authenticate_admin
@admin_routes.route('/xxxx')
def basic():
    return render_template('xxx/xxxx.html', user=user, 
                                   logout=users.create_logout_url('/'))
```

The exception i get for the above code is

```
UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'nickname'
```

Comment: Can you try changing the order of the decorators? the function you want to decorate with `@admin_routes` is the function that is already decorated by `authenticate_admin` right? It feels like the `@admin_routes` assigns the route to the function `basic` and when you route to `/xxxx` it routes using the function `basic` and your `render_template` uses `user.nickname` where your `user` is `None`

Comment: @hgwells. Yes, changing the order has worked. I wonder why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of decorators matter. If the code is structured as in the question, `admin_routes` decorates `basic` and returns a function (`funcA`). That function, `funcA`, is then decorated by `authenticate_admin` which returns `funcB`. So the function that actually is assigned as callback for the route is the function given to `admin_routes` which is `basic` and not the decorated version of basic (`funcA`, or `funcB`). So your `funcB` is never called and hence your authentication logic is not executed

When you change the order to

```
@admin_routes.route('/xxxx')
@authenticate_admin
def basic():
    ...
```

Here `authenticate_admin` returns the decorated function `funcA` which is then decorated by `admin_routes`. So the function assigned as a callback is `funcA` not `basic`. So when you go to `/xxxx`, `funcA` and your authentication logic is executed.

The error seems to be when you navigate to `/xxxx` when you are not logged in, it tries to `render_template` with `user=None` and most likely your template uses `user.nickname` which is an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the return value of `authenticate_admin` to be the `authenticate_and_call` function, not its invocation `authenticate_and_call()`:

```
    return authenticate_and_call
```

Comment: Tried it I am still getting the exception UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'nickname'

Comment: I'm not familiar with flask, so I'm not sure about this one: my decorators also don't use `return` in front of the equivalents of the `redirect` and the `func` calls...