# Combining Flask Blueprints with Flask-JWT

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-jwt

I am developing a `Flask` 0.12 app with Blueprints and I am trying to use `Flask-JWT` (0.3.2) for authentication.

None of the tutorials that I can see for Flask-JWT use Blueprints.

There is a usually a block of code in each example, that does something like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identity)
```

In a blueprinted flask app the structure tends to be more like this:

**__init__.py**:

```
from swarm.controllers.main import main
from swarm.controllers.grid import grid
from swarm.controllers.address import address

def create_app(object_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(grid)
    app.register_blueprint(address)
```

**controllers/main.py:**

```
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
```

**controllers/grid.py:**

```
grid = Blueprint('grid', __name__)
```

**controllers/address.py:**

```
address = Blueprint('address', __name__)
```

How would I reference `Flask-JWT` and use its decorators in the controllers?

It might prove easier to answer this question by showing how to add JWT decorators to a standard example such as [blueprintexample](https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/master/examples/blueprintexample) in the flask source code o [Michał Karzyński's REST API demo](https://github.com/postrational/rest_api_demo).

Comment: A blueprint just enables you to organize your code around conceptual chunks of your application, it actually is not different really at all from a normal Flask app. The code you are showing above from `main.py, grid.py, address.py` you should put into `__init__.py` files to make them proper python modules. instantiate Flask-JWT in your main `__init__.py` file, then import it from the blueprint you want to use and decorate those routes. I usually have an __auth__ blueprint that manages login, logout, callback, etc. w/ my authentication service (using JWT).

Comment: I didn't quite follow why each controller needs its own controllers/mycontroller/__init__.py rather than just controllers/mycontroller.py

Comment: I have tried your approach & I seem to get circular references in my code.

Comment: For example, tried it with this repo: https://github.com/postrational/rest_api_demo and it fell in a heap using this approach:
```app.py: jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identify)``` ```api/grid/endpoints/posts.py: from rest_api_demo.app import jwt```

Comment: NOTE for newcomers: use instead, the Flask-JWT-Extended, which is found https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, has been updated more recently and has better documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've built a simple example that enables use of `Flask-JWT` decorators.

The file structure:

```
server
├── app
|   ├── admin # blueprint
|   |   ├── __init__.py
|   |   ├── views.py
|   ├── __init__.py
├── config.py
└── run.py
```

---

First, create a blueprint called `admin` and import its views

```
# file: server/app/admin/init.py
from flask import Blueprint

admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__)

from . import views
```

The `admin` blueprint has one view. Here, we import the `admin` blueprint and some `flask_jwt` stuff so we can properly access their decorators:

```
from flask_jwt import jwt_required, current_identity
from . import admin

# file: server/app/admin/views.py
@admin.route('/protected')
@jwt_required()
def protected():
    return '%s' % current_identity
```

Now create the flask app, create the `JWT` instance, and register the `admin` blueprint to the flask application:

```
# file: server/app/__init__.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_jwt import JWT
from werkzeug.security import safe_str_cmp

from .admin import admin

# skipping over jwt authenticate() and identity() creation
# https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/
# ...

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object('config')

jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identity)

app.register_blueprint(admin, url_prefix='/admin')
```

And finally, set up your script manager:

```
from flask_script import Manager, Server

from server.app import app

manager = Manager(app)

# Turn on debugger by default and reloader
manager.add_command("runserver", Server(
    use_debugger = True,
    use_reloader = True,
    host = '0.0.0.0',
    port = 5000)
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

Now, if we go to our /admin/protected url, we will see that JWT is up and running:

```
{
  "description": "Request does not contain an access token",
  "error": "Authorization Required",
  "status_code": 401
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed & clear answer. I first created your app & got it working and then put the appropriate changes in my app. All is Good.

Comment: One other thing that I noticed that I had been doing wrong was putting the @jwt_required decorator around the API class methods rather than around the class itself.
This is the correct approach:

Comment: `@jwt_required()`
`@api.route('/api/user/<int:uid>')`
`class User(Resource):`

Comment: @ChrisGuest `api.route` must be the outermost decorator. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31757446/5819113

Comment: how to write a revoke token method in common for all registered blueprints controllers